# How do I move my Amazon books to new iPad

Tags: ipad, upgrade, aws

If I upgrade to a new iPad will all of my Amazon content be moved over?

Comment: In which application are you holding your Amazon content? Kindle?

Answer (score 5):

All Kindle content is ultimately stored in the cloud (with copies on each device). You should be able to easily download all of your content to your new iPad by logging into logging into your Amazon on a compatible app (the Kindle app is the only one I know of that does this).